# convert A1 formula and Array into L1C1 formula and vice-versa

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2007

Is there a way to convert the fashion A1 formula and array into the fashion L1C1 formula and vice-versa in Excel?

Comment: If you want clearer answers, then I suggest you give an example of what you have as input and what you want as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Application.ConvertFormula` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223281%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

```
Application.ConvertFormula(Formula, FromReferenceStyle, ToReferenceStyle, ToAbsolute, RelativeTo)
```

Comment: Does it possible give an practical example? Is there another way to resolve the problem?

Comment: @jbofelli A practical example is available if you click the link. Another way is definitely there, it would involve writing your own formula parser.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the question but you can interchange the formula type of a cell/range using combinations of the methods below

```
Sub test()
With Sheet1
    Set Rng = .Range("A1")

    'method1
    Formula = Rng.FormulaR1C1
    Rng.FormulaR1C1 = Formula

    'method2
    Formula = Rng.FormulaR1C1
    Rng.Formula = Formula

    'method3
    Formula = Rng.Formula
    Rng.Formula = Formula

    'method4
    Formula = Rng.Formula
    Rng.FormulaArray = Formula

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By Chance, I was looking the book "VBA and Macros for Microsoft Office Excel 2007 - Bill Jelen" he says that:
1)In the Editor VBA;
2)type CTRL+G;
3)type "Print ActiveCell.FormulaL1C1"; 
4)press Enter;

Comment: With this steps you can convert A1 formula into L1C1( or R1C1) formula.